# ATX power supply only 0.1A from 12V rail?

Tags: power-supply, atx

I have a project which requires a high current output (potentially 60A). Rather than get a lab bench supply, I got hold of a Corsair ATX AX1200i that can supply a max of 100.4A on the 12V wire.

I've followed an instructables guide on getting an ATX to run without being attached to a motherboard (soldered the green wire to a ground) and got a 12V wire from the 24 pin connector, as well as a ground wire.

However, when I connect the supply to my circuit (mainly a Peltier configuration), the peltiers barely cool. What's more is that the current seems to be throttling to 0.1A.

What am I doing wrong/ am I using the wrong connector (+12V wire on the 24pin connector as opposed to any others).

Comment: It looks you modified the power supply, and did something wrong during that modification. Let me get some necessary tools (I have no idea where I put them) and I will tell you exactly what you did wrong

Comment: You may find that you'll need to load *all* the rails in order to keep any of them in regulation.

Comment: To add to Ignacio's comment - that means all of the different output voltages, not just all of the +12V wires. (and for 60A your should be using more than a single +12V wire already)

Comment: A schematic would certainly help here...

Comment: +12V wires are typically yellow and the ground wires are black. parallel all the black and yellow wires and connect them to your load. (or at-least use as many blacks to the ground input as yellows to the other input and use all the yellows.

Comment: Okay so I checked my wiring and everything seems to be correct. The only modification I really made was to solder the green PS-ON wire to a ground. 

I followed this diagram http://cdn.overclock.net/a/a4/900x900px-LL-a44ab88f_CorsairAX1200iPinout.jpeg

I can't find a circuit diagram of the PSU, but it says that it only has one rail. I tried to load the 5V cables of the ATX using a 33R 25W power resistor I had lying around. However, I still can only get a low current (it seems to be able to kick out 0.2A)...